# How do I fix phonegap framework missing

Tags: cordova

I just inherited a project from another developer and the phonegap.framework in xcode is red which I am assuming is missing. How would I include it so the project builds successfully. I have installed phonegap and cordova on my machine but now I am stuck at this step.

Comment: Read the PhoneGap / Cordova installation tutorial, or re-run the PhoneGap installation ?

Comment: Would I have to rerun it into the project folder or in a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the PhoneGap version that is used in the project - you may be able to get a hint by looking at your project's www/index.html file and locate the script include tag to see which version is used.

Download the appropriate version, read the getting started guide with iOS at http://docs.phonegap.com

You may be able to run the command line tool to update the CordovaLib reference:

```
[CordovaHome]/bin/update_cordova_subproject Path/To/Your/project.xcodeproj
```

Comment: This seems to be the version: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You saved me hours. Thanks so much it worked right away when I installed the right version.